# An algorithm for computing $\pi^{-1}$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, recurrence-relations, pi

[Wikipedia: Borwein's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein%27s_algorithm#Cubic_convergence_.281991.29) claims

> Start out by setting
>
> $$\begin{align} a_0 & = \frac{1}{3} \\
>                        s_0 & = \frac{\sqrt{3} - 1}{2}
>          \end{align} $$
>
> Then iterate
>
> $$ \begin{align} r_{k+1} & = \frac{3}{1 + 2(1-s_k^3)^{1/3}} \\
>                        s_{k+1} & = \frac{r_{k+1} - 1}{2} \\
>                        a_{k+1} & = r_{k+1}^2 a_k - 3^k(r_{k+1}^2-1)
>          \end{align} $$
>
> **Then $a_k$ converges cubically to $1/\pi$;** that is, each
>   iteration approximately triples the number of correct digits.

sadly without direct reference or proof. Where (precise reference) can I find the proof, or even better, could it be summarized in an answer? (I'm more interested in seeing *that* the recurrence relation converges to $1/\pi$ than in the rate of convergence.)

Comment: Thank you for the reference. The algorithm is just great - it gives $5$ correct digits at the first step and $21$ correct digits at the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this equivalent to Theorem 6.1 [here](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/organics/papers/garvan/paper/html/node10.html#SECTION00060000000000000000)?  The reference is to
J.M. Borwein and P.B. Borwein, A cubic counterpart of Jacobi's identity and the AGM, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc., 323 (1991), 691--701.

Comment: Looks to be close enough in any case. Thank you!